# Seemingly simple path finding problem, but graph with travelling salesman or shortest path does not work

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computational-geometry, shortest-path, hamiltonian-path

I am looking for an algorithm to a problem that I encountered when working with 3D modeling:

On a 3D triangle surface mesh, I have multiple lines, some of them are open, some are closed. The are on one side of each line is defined as `inside`, the area on the other side of the line as `outside`. Inside is shown with small strokes next to the line. Now I have to close all open lines with connecting lines. The end goal is to use the lines to perform a boolean operation on the mesh. Rules:

1. It is possible to connect multiple open lines together, or to connect an open line with itself.
2. The solution must be such that all areas that are defined through the lines are consistent on whether they are inside or outside.
3. All open lines must be closed in the final solution.

At the moment, I am tackling the problem with a planar graph and looking for paths through the graph. I tried the shortest path and traveling salesman/hamiltonian path, but both fail to comply with rule 2. Since the closed lines are needed to find the correct solution, and they are not part of the graph, possibly a graph is the wrong tool in the first place.

I appreciate any ideas. The more precise, the better - step-by-step instructions or pseudocode is perfect - but also if you just have a rough idea in mind, please share.

Edit:
Some clarifications in response to comments:
The black lines cannot overlap. The area of the closed polygons must be bigger than 0. I am looking for any solution atm. The open lines are open polygonal chains.

Below are some images for clarification:

[image: Graph.]

[image: A correct solution.]

[image: Another correct solution.]

[image: A wrong solution.]

Comment: "The solution must be such that all areas that are defined through the lines are consistent on whether they contain plusses or nothing" What does it mean to be consistent w.r.t this? Is the last example wrong because it violates 3? Maybe you can try to state the problem more formally. Are the crosses and lines objects in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes exactly. To the right of the lightning bolt is a "nothing" area, to the left there is a "plus" area. Since they are not separated by a line, the same area is "nothing" and "plus" at the same time. This is illegal.

Comment: @idmean Okay the cross thing seems to make it very unclear. I will update the question with a different approach, it will take some minutes.

Comment: @idmean I edited text and images, does this make more sense?

Comment: Yes, the problem is a lot clearer now. How are these lines described? Are these curves? Or polygons?

Comment: @idmean Great. They are open polygonal chains.

Comment: Can the input polygons overlap? Is there some minimum area the closed polygons (output) must enclose or something? Also are you looking for any solution or is there some optimality you want to achieve? (I know many questions, but it's an interesting problem.)

Comment: Are you only interested in finding a solution, or is there some aspect of a valid solution you are trying to optimize? One possible solution would be to choose a side for the outer face, enclose all closed curves inconsistent by closing a single open curve, and close the remaining open curves individually. (this assumes all open curves lie in a single connected component of $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the closed curves, if this is not the case, then repeat this for each component) This could be a pretty bad solution if you are trying to minimize the length of the curves, though.

Comment: @idmean I am happy to answer any questions, glad you find the problem interesting. If by input polygons you mean the black lines, then no, they cannot overlap. The area of the closed polygons must be bigger than 0, otherwise there is no minimum. At the moment, I am looking for any solution. The more computationally efficient, the better.

Comment: @Discretelizard I am currently interested in finding any solution, if anything I would optimize for computational efficiency. Thank you for the idea, I need some time to think about if and how this would work in my case and will get back to you.

Comment: @Discretelizard I have given this some thoughts and I have some questions:

What to do when/how to avoid that a line that closes an inconsistent closed curve also encloses a consistent close curve?

There are two options to close each open line considering inside/outside. When I know which one is needed, how to compute? Atm I use shortestPath for this, but it won't guarantuee correct orientation.

Comment: @Discretelizard I am working on a 3D triangle surface mesh.

Comment: Please don't leave clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question to clarify it so that point will be clearer to others, then flag comments as 'no longer needed' once they have been addressed.  Thank you!